# How to open Android app by clicking any URL on facebook (Facebook deep link for android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, deep-linking, applinks

I'm following the [Facebook doc for app link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android) but can't figure out how to setup app link on android for facebook. I've tried to follow other documentations but can't get proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for dynamic link using Fire base console.

```
 1> create the account in fire base console.
 2> Create the project and
 select the dynamic link option. this is the image where on left side menu you can select dynamic link option.
```

[image: Click on New Dynamic Link]

[image: After creation of link successfully goto link and select link details.]

[image: Share the info of dyanmic link to your server Php/java guy]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I needed the process for facebook :)